# class text-white with tailwind does not work

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I try to put a text in white color but it does not work why?

**html.erb**

```
<h1 class="text-3xl text-center pt-5 bg-green-800 text-white">Epicery</h1>  <!--  here it works very well the text-white -->
     <div class="flex pt-5 pb-5 bg-green-800">
         <div class="mx-auto">
             <ul class="flex">
                 <li class="mr-6 text-white"> <!--  here it does not work text-white -->
                     <a class="text-white text-sm hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-white p-4 rounded" href="#">Link</a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
```

I imported the tailwind cdn

**application.html.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 73):

If you want to include all of the default colors in Tailwind, you have to include the new colors in an "extends" bracket so it won't overwrite everything else.

Here's an example:

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                my_color: '#4dcb7a',
            },
        },
    },
},
```

Comment: Am I understanding this right, that I have to include some random color so that I can include the default colors?

Comment: That's correct @Olli

Comment: This is the correct answer, wish it would default to extend and you would have to specifically overwrite the default colors.

Comment: @Olli This is incorrect. There are two types of config: `{theme: {colors: {}}}` or `{theme: {extend: {colors: {}}}`. The former overrides colors and while the latters extends the base colors. So, OP must have overridden colors. You definitely don't need to add a random color to include all the base colors

Answer (score 6):

You may have accidentally removed colors you expect by default by adding `theme.textColor` settings to `tailwind.config.js` I also had classes disappear from Tailwind compiled styles.

Tailwind resets all links, moving to an opt-in style paradigm.

If your config file **does not** include a theme entry for `textColor`, the default includes colors that cause classes to be generated... like `text-white` and `text-black`.

Be sure to add EVERY color you need and expect!

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    textColor: {
      primary: blue,
      secondary: purple,
      white: "#FFF",  <<< this
      black: "#000",  <<< this
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: I don't think you need to include white and black unless you're going for an off-white and just calling it white.  If you move the colours within the "extend" brackets and remove the white and black the default tailwind colours should work (which includes white and black).   See @Noah Bar-Shain's answer above.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `text-[color:white]` in your class

Answer (score 1):

in my case I had my colors: {} object outside of the extend object.

Before: (and the custom colors were being utilised with no issues)

```
  module.exports = {
  content: [ "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
      'dark-green': '#4e6c50',
      'green-grey': '#A2A378',
      'brown': '#c1ae93',
      'beige': '#a7ab90'
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

After:

```
  module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'dark-green': '#4e6c50',
        'green-grey': '#A2A378',
        'brown': '#c1ae93',
        'beige': '#a7ab90'
      }
    },

  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

You should now be able to use text-white and other properties with no issues

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, as you can see below on [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/9BppUPFTnx). Both the heading and a tag are displayed in white.

Maybe you have another css file that interferes with tailwind's styles.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 class="pt-5 text-3xl text-center text-white bg-green-800">Epicery</h1>
<div class="flex pt-5 pb-5 bg-green-800">
  <div class="mx-auto">
    <ul class="flex">
      <li class="mr-6 text-white">
        <a class="p-4 text-sm rounded hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-white" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```